# Inverse Rotation of Axes

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have rotated point coordinates of original coordinates.
I am trying to find original coordinates from rotated coordinates..

For example;

Original Points: `x=0, y=60000`

Degree: `-45`

If i calculate with here:
https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1223522781

I found the `x=-42,426.406871193, y=42,426.406871193`

When I look here, the result is correct.

Now i want to calculate,

If i have,

```
degree = -45
rotated_x = -42,426.406871193
rotated_y = 42,426.406871193
```

How can i find original coordinates with above values?

Result must be = `(0, 60000)`

Comment: Do you know the 2 by 2 Rotation Matrix?

Comment: @imranfat i am actually software engineer so i am really bad at math. once I felt the need to do such a calculation. I would be very happy if you could help me with this. Thank you.. I just need to formula

Comment: Let me type some stuff up. I think the Rotation matrix is the east for any rotation (about the Origin)

Comment: I check out that link and there is a problem with it. In mathematics a positive rotation is AGAINST the clock. (Counter clockwise). But when I played with it, it rotated a point 45 degrees WITH the clock. This is mathematically not right. You got to watch that, because putting $+45$ in the Rotation matrix is AGAINST the clock and $-45$ is WITH the clock. That link does it the other way around! BEWARE!!

Comment: @imranfat i recognized it, i made an algorithm like your say. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the 2 by 2 Rotation Matrix to rotate a point $\theta$ degrees counter clockwise, is given by $ \begin{bmatrix}cos\theta & -sin\theta\\sin\theta & cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$. The derivation of this matrix can be found elsewhere on the internet. So if I want to rotate $ \begin{bmatrix}-42426 \\42426 \end{bmatrix}$ "back" I can plug in $\theta=-45$ into the matrix and multiply $ \begin{bmatrix}cos(-45) & -sin(-45)\\sin(-45) & cos(-45)\end{bmatrix}$$ \begin{bmatrix}-42426 \\42426 \end{bmatrix}$ and this will give $ \begin{bmatrix}0 \\60000 \end{bmatrix}$ (Forgive my rounding)